# Is there any method to convert any location in global frame to NED frame and from NED frame to global frame in drone-kit?

Tags: coordinate-transformation, dronekit-python, 3dr

I am trying to make predict the crash location of a quadrotor if propulsion fails. My main objective is to help the search after a quad crashes.

Now my "Trajectory" class takes the positon and orientaion an velocity of the quad in NED frame.

I use vehicle.location.local_frame to obtian position in NED frame and vehicle.velocity to obtain velocity in NED frame and use vehicle.attitude to obtain orientaion

Using this information and some basic newtownian dynamics,my "Trajectory" class outputs the probable crash location in NED frame(x,y,z) and i want to convert the co-ordinate of the crash site to global(lat,lon,alt). Is there any function/methods to do that,

IF not how can i calculate kit?

The NED frame has origin at the arming location of the drone.